# Pandas - check if a value is in a column and if not re-ask for the input

Tags: python, pandas

I'm sure this question has been answered on stack overflow but can't seem to find anything.

I have a dataframe with 3 columns: 'hobby', 'first_name', 'last_name'. it looks like this when opened (in notepad):

```
,hobby,first_name,last_name
0,football,james,smith
1,tennis,jill,murray
```

(the first column is an index)
I want to ask the user for an input of a hobby and if it is not in the hobby column reask for the input. I have this piece of code and am very confused of why it is not working:

```
hobby = input('enter a hobby')
while hobby not in df['hobby']:
    hobby = input('enter a hobby')
```

This turns out to be an infinite loop and even when I type in a hobby first which is in the column it doesn't work

Any help would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For repeating input, a while loop is always recommended;

```
while True:             # Loop continuously
    inp = raw_input()   # Get the input
    if (df['hobby'] == hobby).any():      # If it is in the column..
        break
```

Comment: Sorry i copied my code wrong if was meant to be while

Comment: @HarryMaguire, this is a suggestion for continuously asking for input, however to make this work correctly you also need to update your statement that checks if the value is in the column as well (see mine compared to yours), that is what is causing you issues. (Thanks to Jezrael)